# Reading the route table on FreeBSD

Tags: network-programming, porting, freebsd, routes

I'm porting an application from Linux to FreeBSD that needs to look at the table of network routes ("route" on Linux or "netstat -r" on FreeBSD).

On Linux, the application simply reads /proc/net/route and /proc/net/inet6_route.

What is the best way to do this programatically on FreeBSD ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in the man page [route(4)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=route&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).  Basically, you `read()` and `write()` a `PF_ROUTE` [socket](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=socket&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).  You can look at the [/sbin/route](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/sbin/route/route.c?rev=1.95.2.1;content-type=text/plain) source for an example.